# Broken responsive design (on iPhone only) - can media queries be forced with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, media-queries

I am having an issue with the responsiveness of my website on a iPhone. From the android and surface devices I have tested this site looks fine. But on Apple devices are giving me major problems.

This is how my website is supposed to look on a mobile phone:

[image: Moonshine on a browser resized]

This is my website inside a browser on a desktop computer:

[image: Moonshine on a PC]

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM:**

On an iPhone my website sort of goes responsive, but sort of doesn't - it looks like this:

[image: Moonshine on a mobile :(]

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

---

Looks to me like the iPhone is picking up some of the responsive rules, but not all of them. For more information I have this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I have tried combinations of these CSS media query rules:

```
@media (max-width: 1100px) and (max-device-width: 1100px)
@media (max-width: 1100px) and (max-device-width: 1100px) {
@media only screen and (max-width : 767px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1280px)
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) and (max-width: 1024px)
```

And alternating between all of these makes no difference, they all produce the same problems shown in the pictures above.

I just want iPhones to pick up on my responsive rules correctly, like everything else does.

Can anyone please help me to shed some light on this issue?

I am really struggling with this, and have been for some time now. Any solution would be appreciated.

I have tried lots of changes to my CSS, but to no avail. So now my current idea here is to try and use javascript to fix the problem.

Is there any way to force a media query with javascript?

Or is there any way I could use javascript to stop iPhones from displaying this website wrong?

But I am not sure if this would work or help. I would prefer a CSS solution, but changing the CSS is making no difference at all, so in desperation I am hoping javascript will help me out.

If it helps, check out the code here - http://www.moonshineandfuggles.com/

Comment: _Or is there any way I could use javascript to stop iPhones from displaying this website wrong?_ - You can use `navigator.userAgent` to find out the user agent and show some message.

Comment: What I meant was, you can stop the page being displayed depending on the user agent. Yep, that doesn't solve your actual issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use below code to load CSS & JS files based on device type, also try setting maximum-scale,user-scalable and height in viewport tag-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, height=device-height"/>



 function loadDeviceSpecificFiles() {
     if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/android/)) {
         loadjscssfile("and_filename.js", "js"); //dynamically load JS
         loadjscssfile("and_filename.css", "css") //dynamically load css
             /*iPhone check*/
     } else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/iphone/) || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/ipad/)) {
         loadjscssfile("ios_filename.js", "js") //dynamically load JS
         loadjscssfile("ios_filename.css", "css") //dynamically load css
     }
 }


 function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) {
     if (filetype == "js") { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
         var fileref = document.createElement('script')
         fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
         fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
     } else if (filetype == "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
         var fileref = document.createElement("link")
         fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
         fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
         fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
     }
     if (typeof fileref != "undefined") document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
 }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for being the only person to respond to my question, after some tweaking Ive managed to get this to work - many thanks!